# i have txt file have numbers like this 888|33/22|000 how can i print only one of 888 or 03/22 or 000

Tags: python-3.x, list, readline

**i have txt file have numbers like this 888|33/22|000 how can i print only one of 888 or 03/22 or 000**

> how can i print only one of 888 or 03/22 or 000

```
888|33/22|000
```

```
with open('jack.txt') as fp:
   line = fp.readline()
   cnt = 1
   while line:
       print(cyan,time.asctime(time.localtime(time.time())),gr,"Plugin or Extension {} \033[1;37;40m : {} ".format(cnt, line.strip()))
       time.sleep(0.0001)
       print (part.of.lin)e


output
888
```

Comment: split and pick one randomly

Answer (score 0):

split and pick one randomly line by line

```
import random
 
x = "888|33/22|000"

x = x.split('|')

print(random.choice(x))
```